# JFreeChart - wrong chart font

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a problem with `XYLineChart`. I don't know how to set the chart font to look like Swing components. When I use this:

```
chart.setTitle(new TextTitle("Tahoma title, style plain, size 11", new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11)));
```

It is still wrong :(

EDIT: When I create the chart in a new frame, the font in the title is good. How do I set all the labels, axis titles, and other texts to the same font size, without bold?

SOLVED :)

```
public static void changeStyle(JFreeChart chart) {
    final StandardChartTheme chartTheme = (StandardChartTheme)StandardChartTheme.createJFreeTheme();
    final Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
    final Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);

    chartTheme.setExtraLargeFont(font);
    chartTheme.setLargeFont(font);
    chartTheme.setRegularFont(font);
    chartTheme.setSmallFont(font);

    chartTheme.setAxisLabelPaint(color);
    chartTheme.setLegendItemPaint(color);
    chartTheme.setItemLabelPaint(color);
    chartTheme.apply(chart);
}
```

Comment: ok, I changed title font and size. But how to change all items font(labels, axis...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the existing title's font, do something like this:

```
chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
```

Addendum:

> How do I change all items' fonts, e.g. labels, axis, etc.?

[`StandardChartTheme`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/StandardChartTheme.html) offers this capability by [operating](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/StandardChartTheme.html#line.115) on individual chart components.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 2 things about XYLineCharts, but it looks like you might be setting the font on the wrong thing. Try setting it on different components.

Not much, but might get you going.

Good luck ;)

Damo